# Как отображать в NSNumberFormatter только введенные данные?

Tags: ios, swift, типы-данных, числа, uitextfield

Использую NSNumberFormatter.
Выглядит это примерно так:

```
      let formatter = NumberFormatter()

      formatter.locale = Locale.current
      formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
      formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 10

      if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

      year = number.doubleValue

      textField.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: year))

      yearLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: year).multiplying(by: 1))
```

При вводе в текстовое поле например цифры "15" отображается "15.00000000", а при вводе "5,085" отображается "5,085000000".

Каким образом можно сократить отображение знаков в textField только до введенных юзером?

Comment: Строчку с форматтером над textField хотелось бы оставить...

Comment: Ну как вариант удаляйте все нули в конце строки.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов:

```
let number = 123.23123

print(String(format: "%.2f", number)) -> 123.23
print(String(format: "%.3f", number)) -> 123.231
```